# Change font color, font size using array

Tags: php, html

How do I change the font color using this code?  I'm just looking for a simple solution but if you want to also suggest how to rewrite it to be SQL injection proof, I would appreciate that too.  Please help as I am still learning.

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<table border='0' width='800' align='center' >";
echo "<td width='40%' align='center'></td>
<td width='20%' align='center'></td>
<td width='40%' align='center'></td>";
echo "</tr>";

$row_number = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $id_actor = $row["id_actor"];
    $idfilm = $row["idfilm"];
    $filmTitle = $row["filmTitle"];
    $filmRole = $row["filmRole"];
    $filmDirector = $row["filmDirector"];

    for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        echo "<td> $row[$i]</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";

    $row_number++;
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `echo"<td> $row[$i]</td>";` , try 
`echo"<td><font color=\"red\"> $row[$i]</font></td>";`

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of your code, insert the following for CSS styling:

```
echo "
<style>
tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
</style>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this example to your problem:

```
<font color="red">This is some text!</font>
```

to solve the problem of font color. Or, you can use CSS styling:

```
style="color: #CC0000;"
```

As about the suggestion to protect yourself against SQL injection it is hard to make any suggestions as your example code does not contain your query, any SQL injection attack has already made its damage when we reach your example code. But for general tips, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Finally, do not forget to protect your client-side against XSS injections which can be used to steal the identity of your users.